# Regex match character except within other characters

Tags: java

Lets say I have a string that is dynamic with any sort of PHP functions/vars/strings used within.

`"test", "test", test("test", test()), "test"`

How would would I match all the `,` parts without capturing sub-functions?

For example I want to capture an array like:

```
  [0] => "test",
  [1] => "test",
  [2] => test("test", test()),
  [3] => "test"
```

I am matching anything inside a functions `(...)` brackets, but not trying to match any sub functions as part of the functions arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code. BUT `(?<!\("test"),` **MUST** be refactorred

```
    String str = "\"test\", \"test\", test(\"test\", test()), \"test\"";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\(\"test\"),");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by refactorred? Do you mean escaped? As far as I know refactoring in Java is the act of renaming a class/package/project and all references.

Comment: This also works only on "test", test is just a placeholder. I am trying to get any dynamic coding content in params. Something like `(?<!\(("|'*).*?("|'*)),` but... works. Lol

Comment: Becasue of the bad  express `(?<!\("test"),`, you should rewrite the express

Comment: Hence the rewrite in above comment.... doesn't answer the problem which is I do not know the expression to accomplish this...